# File Copy Tool w/ Producer/Consumer Model

Tags: c++, synchronization, file-copying, consumer, producer

so I was looking over my next school assignment, and I'm baffled. I figured I would come to the experts for some direction. My knowledge on synchronization is severely lacking, and I didn't do so hot on the "mcopyfile" assignment it refers to. Terrible would probably be a good word for it. If I could get some direction on how to accomplish this problem, it would be much appreciated. Not looking for someone to do my assignment, just need someone to point me in the right direction. baby steps.

> Based on the multi-threaded file copy tool
>   (mcopyfile) you have created in Lab 2, now please use a worker
>   pool (Producer-Consumer model) implementation that uses a fixed
>   number of threads to handle the load (regardless how many files in the
>   directory to copy). Your program should create 1 file copy producer
>   thread and multiple file copy consumer threads (this number is taken
>   from the command-line argument). The file copy producer thread will
>   generate a list of (source and destination) file descriptors in a buffer
>   structure with bounded size. Each time when the producer accesses the buffer it will write
>   one (source, destination) file entry (per visit). And all file copy
>   consumer threads will read from this buffer, execute the actual file
>   copy task, and remove the corresponding file entry (each consumer
>   will consume one entry each time). Both producer and consumer
>   threads will write a message to standard output giving the file name
>   and the completion status (e.g., for producer: “Completing putting
>   file1 in the buffer”, for consumer: “Completing copying file1 to …”).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming, you know how to spawn threads, let me break down the problem for you. There are following components:

1. **Producer**. It generates *Tasks* for the *Consumers* based on the source directory input parameter.
2. **Task**. A task is information for *Consumer* to execute its copy task. Namely a tuple of source file descriptor and destination file descriptor.
3. **Queue**. It is the central piece of communication between *Producer* and *Consumer*. Producers writes *Tasks* to *Queue* and *Consumer* consumes it.
4. **Consumer**. You have a pool of actual workers that take *Task* as input and executes copy operation.

Now as per the question, spawn a thread for producer and *n* threads for consumers. And this is what the threads do:

- **Producer thread**

  1. For list of files in the source directory:

     1. Task <- (Source file path, destination file path)
     2. Acquire lock on *Queue*
     3. Write *Task* to queue
     4. Release lock on *Queue*
     5. Acquire lock on *stdout*
     6. Write to *stdout*
     7. Release lock on *stdout*
- **Consumer thread**

  1. While True:

     1. If size of queue == 0:

        1. Sleep for some time
     2. Else:

        1. Acquire lock on *Queue*
        2. Dequeue a *Task*
        3. Release lock on *Queue*
        4. Execute copy operation
        5. Acquire lock on *stdout*
        6. Write to *stdout*
        7. Release lock on *stdout*

I hope this helps.

Comment: The assignment could also be understood so that the producer reads the source files and produces tasks for writing (parts of) destination files.

Comment: @SimonRichter, This from the OP's question: `The file copy producer thread will generate a list of (source and destination) file descriptors in a buffer structure`.

Comment: ya i think so, I plan to start on this sometime today. thanks for the quick response!

Comment: Vikas, I have posted some code for this assignment and am receiving a segfault, i would be interested in your opinion and assessment of the code if it's not too much to ask :)

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13148673/segfault-with-producer-consumer-file-copy

Answer (score 0):

Your assignment looks pretty straightforward to me once you know what API/library you'll use for the threading functionality.

First, you'll parse the command-line argument and create the specified number of threads, then from the main thread obtain the list of files in the folder and start putting them in an array (like a std::vector) that is shared among the threads and is synchronized with a mutex (or a critical section on Windows). Whenever one of the consumer threads acquires the mutex, it makes a copy of a file entry in the array, removes that entry from the array, releases the mutex so that another thread can start doing the same, and starts copying the file represented by the entry it removed from the array.

I would give you some code snippets, but you didn't say what API/library you're using for the threading functionality.